# Spring Data JPA Relationships

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

here I'am, trying to get a better understanding of JPA Relationships in SpringBoot.

Those Entities has been created following some XML configuration files.
I'm not used to XML and I'm trying to improve my Java/SpringBoot @Annotation skills.

I'll show you 3 Entities with a OneToOne & ManyToOne annotations.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

### Questions

1. **In Driver -< ServiceRequestDriverVehicle (@OneToMany) the mappedBy="driverId" references the current Driver id field or the JoinColumn(name="driverId") from the other Entity?** e.g.: In Vehicle Entity mappedBy use vehicle, which if comes from *ServiceRequestDriverVehicle* it's named as vehicleId @JoinColumn(name="vehicleId") but it's field name is vehicle, so why where is using vehicle instead of vehicleId as in the Driver case does? *Again this is abstracted from an XML configuration that can be wrong.*
2. **Are the arrows from the images pointing the right meaning of the Annotation?** I mean, is the annotation taking the entity/class of the annotated field to make the relationship mapping?
3. **In the @OneToOne relationship(Driver), is the referencedColumnName="ID" mandatory/necessary or OneToOne is automatically linked to the PK (id)**
4. **I have a MySQL model where the Set fields do not appear, should I Annotate those as @Transient or the LAZY fetch is enough?**

#### Thank you for your answers, I hope this can solve future misunderstandings

Comment: What I would do is hook all this up to an in memory H2 database and check the relationships in the web UI. The mappings and referenced columns can get confusing at times especially when we have relationships like these which are One -> Many -> One. Also, when you say the set fields do not appear, what do you mean? There should tables with names `SERVICE_REQUEST_DRIVER_VEHICLE`, `GEO_LOCATION` and `DRIVER`. Spring JPA does not create the tables unless you set hbm2ddl.auto.

Comment: @DhirenDash Hi thank you for your tips, What i meant with Set is that e.g.: private Set<ServiceRequestDriverVehicle> serviceRequestDriverVehicle from "Driver" class does not appear on the MySQL model, to do that is enough with Fetch.LAZY (I know this is about retrieving data from the DB) or do I have to Annotate it as Transient too?? (Note: in XML file does NOT appear as Transient)